# Does a man having a vasectomy mean i cant go to heaven?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 23:1 says

> He that is wounded in the stones, or hath his privy member cut off, shall not enter into the congregation of the lord.

Does this mean if I, as a man, have had a vasectomy will not enter into heaven?

I'm still new and learning the understanding of the Torah. Can someone please clarify the meaning of this verse?

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Perhaps if you are interested in doctrinal questions of judaism, you might want to ask this question on Mi Yoneda. This site is more for exegesis of difficult passages.

Comment: Sorry, but questions like this aren't on-topic here. The only thing I'll ask is why do you think this verse has anything to do with heaven at all?

Comment: Vasectomy might be morally objected on [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onan) grounds; the passage you quoted, however, does not imply infirm men are unable to attain salvation any more than similar ones, asking that lepers be socially isolated, do not imply that the ill are unable to inherit God's kingdom.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that is question is valid for this site (we do not give advice at all!!) so let me offer the comments of the Prophet Isaiah 56:3-7

> Let no **foreigner** who has joined himself to the LORD say, “The LORD
> will utterly exclude me from His people.”
>
> And let the **eunuch** not say, “I am but a dry tree.”
>
> For this is what the LORD says: “To the **eunuchs** who keep My
> Sabbaths, who choose what pleases Me and hold fast to My covenant— I
> will give them, in My house and within My walls, a memorial and a name
> better than that of sons and daughters. I will give them an
> everlasting name that will not be cut off.
>
> And the **foreigners** who join themselves to the LORD to minister to
> Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who
> keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My
> covenant— I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful
> in My house of prayer.
>
> Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for
> My house will be called a **house of prayer for all the nations**.”
> (see also  Matt 21:13, Mark 11:17, and Luke 19:46)

We also read in 1 John 4:8, 16 that "God is love".  That is as much advice as we can give here.

Answer (score 0):

11 Wherefore remember, that ye being in time past Gentiles in the flesh, who are called Uncircumcision by that which is called the Circumcision in the flesh made by hands;
12 That at that time ye were without Christ, being aliens from the commonwealth of Israel, and strangers from the covenants of promise, having no hope, and without God in the world:
13 But now in Christ Jesus ye who sometimes were far off are made nigh by the blood of Christ.
14 For he is our peace, who hath made both one, and hath broken down the middle wall of partition between us;
15 Having abolished in his flesh the enmity, even the law of commandments contained in ordinances; for to make in himself of twain one new man, so making peace;
16 And that he might reconcile both unto God in one body by the cross, having slain the enmity thereby:
17 And came and preached peace to you which were afar off, and to them that were nigh.
18 For through him we both have access by one Spirit unto the Father.
19 Now therefore ye are no more strangers and foreigners, but fellowcitizens with the saints, and of the household of God;
20 And are built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Jesus Christ himself being the chief corner stone;
21 In whom all the building fitly framed together groweth unto an holy temple in the Lord:
22 In whom ye also are builded together for an habitation of God through the Spirit.
(Ephesians 2)

26 And the angel of the Lord spake unto Philip, saying, Arise, and go toward the south unto the way that goeth down from Jerusalem unto Gaza, which is desert.
27 And he arose and went: and, behold, a man of Ethiopia, an eunuch of great authority under Candace queen of the Ethiopians, who had the charge of all her treasure, and had come to Jerusalem for to worship,
28 Was returning, and sitting in his chariot read Esaias the prophet.
29 Then the Spirit said unto Philip, Go near, and join thyself to this chariot.
30 And Philip ran thither to him, and heard him read the prophet Esaias, and said, Understandest thou what thou readest?
31 And he said, How can I, except some man should guide me? And he desired Philip that he would come up and sit with him.
32 The place of the scripture which he read was this, He was led as a sheep to the slaughter; and like a lamb dumb before his shearer, so opened he not his mouth:
33 In his humiliation his judgment was taken away: and who shall declare his generation? for his life is taken from the earth.
34 And the eunuch answered Philip, and said, I pray thee, of whom speaketh the prophet this? of himself, or of some other man?
35 Then Philip opened his mouth, and began at the same scripture, and preached unto him Jesus.
36 And as they went on their way, they came unto a certain water: and the eunuch said, See, here is water; what doth hinder me to be baptized?
37 And Philip said, If thou believest with all thine heart, thou mayest. And he answered and said, I believe that Jesus Christ is the Son of God.
38 And he commanded the chariot to stand still: and they went down both into the water, both Philip and the eunuch; and he baptized him.
39 And when they were come up out of the water, the Spirit of the Lord caught away Philip, that the eunuch saw him no more: and he went on his way rejoicing.
40 But Philip was found at Azotus: and passing through he preached in all the cities, till he came to Caesarea.
(Acts 8)